# Описание бинов аннотациями

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

По совету одноформучан пробую описывать бины аннотациями и конфигурировать классом. 
При деплое в браузере в трейсе выдает следующее

> Stack Trace org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private ua.service.impl.ClientServiceImpl
>   ua.controller.MainController.clientService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'service': Injection of autowired dependencies
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private ua.dao.impl.ClientDaoImpl
>   ua.service.impl.ClientServiceImpl.clientDaoImpl; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'clientDaoImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   ua.dao.impl.ClientDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [ua/config/WebConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   ua.config.WebConfig.getSessionFactory()] threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:79)
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:220)
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:163)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Есть классы:

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan ("ua")
public class WebConfig {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean (name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        logger.info("get Session Factory");
        return sessionFactory;

    }

    @Bean
    public ClientDaoImpl dao(){
        return new ClientDaoImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientServiceImpl service(){
        return new ClientServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

Интерфейс ДАО и его реализация

```
public interface ClientDao  {

        public void addClient(Client client);

        public List<Client> listClient();

        public void removeClient (Client client);

}


@Repository
public class ClientDaoImpl implements ClientDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addClient(Client client) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(client);
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Client> listClient() {
        List<Client> result = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Client.class).list();
        sessionFactory.close();
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    public void removeClient(Client client) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(client);
        sessionFactory.close();

    }
}
```

Интерфейс Service и его реализация

```
public interface ClientService {

    public void addClient(Client client);

    public List<Client> listClient();

    public void removeClient(Client client);
}



@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDaoImpl clientDaoImpl;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addClient(Client client) {
        clientDaoImpl.addClient(client);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Client> listClient() {
        return clientDaoImpl.listClient();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removeClient(Client client) {
        clientDaoImpl.removeClient(client);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Qualifier("service")
    @Autowired
    private ClientServiceImpl clientService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView mainPage (){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        List<Client> allClient = clientService.listClient();
        modelAndView.addObject("allClient", allClient);
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }


}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Blog Servlet</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servletController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>ua.config</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servletController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/postschema</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">peroser12</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="ua.model.Client"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Как понимаю есть ошибка в описании бинов и sessionFactory. Но именно тот механизм на котором идёт исключения- найти не могу. 
Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: В стектрейсе явно написано где ошибка `resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found `. Если у вас maven, то в classpath копируется **содержимое** каталога `src/main/resources`, а не сам каталог. Т.е. указывать нужно только имя файла.

Comment: И пожалуйста, в следующий раз оформляйте стектрейсы/логи как код, а не как цитату.

Comment: @enzo частично решило проблему. В данный момент в трейсе следующее.
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\ua\config\WebConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:260)`

Comment: @Roman Хорошо. спасибо.

Comment: @Дмитрий это уже другая проблема - наверное, намудрили в maven с зависимостями. Нереально в одном треде последовательно разбирать все ошибки, которые у вас возникнут пока вы учитесь. Их может быть много, и все будут требовать разных вводных. Вам нужно либо изменить подход - задавать вопросы "Как правильно сделать X?", либо учиться читать и разбирать стектрейсы, либо оформлять по одному вопросу на каждый кейс. А лучше все сразу :)

Comment: @enzo хорошее замечание) спасибо)
учту замечание. Только как теперь отметить, что вопрос с ответом?) новичек, ничего не поделаешь :-)

Answer (score 2):

У вас в ДАО должно быть что-то на подобии

```
private static SessionFactory sesFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Это, собственно, создаст SessionFactory, а вы пытаетесь внедрить то, чего ещё нет в контексте Spring. Но этот способ далеко не лучший.

А вот конфигурация для Спринга:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ua.dp.daragan.spring000.domain" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

После этого можно и Autowired в DAO прописать:

```
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateSpitterDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
```